# Uploading folder or zip file and get file paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, zip

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask.

I am attempting to upload a directory of files to a rails app. Now I know this is possible with `multiple` and `webkitdirectory`attributes but what I would like to do is somehow try and obtain the filea relative path inside the folder.

I am even trying to see if its more possible if I were to zip up the folder and then extract it server side but looking at `rubyzip` there doesn't seem to be any obvious way of grabbing the files relative path from within the source folder.